# Require.js - 'no define call' on safari ipad2

Tags: javascript, safari, requirejs

Error: No define call for bootstrap-hover-dropdown
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine

on Safari on ipad2

I think that my configuration is correct. It looks like:

```
    requirejs.config({
paths: {
    'bootstrap-hover-dropdown': 'myPath/bootstrap-hover-dropdown'},
shim: {
    'bootstrap-hover-dropdown': {deps: ['bootstrap'], exports: 'jQuery.fn.dropdownHover'}
}
```

});

bootstrap is also defined in the same way.
Can anyone give me any hint how to solve this problem? On desktop version of browsers: Safari, Chrome, FF, IE and other everything is ok.

update: it also doesn't work on iPhone safari and chrome. So I presume it is the matter of mobile browsers

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be related to the library bootstrap-hover-dropdown and the version that you use. I used to use it and I had the same issue. Previously this lib had problem with mobile clients and it broke chaining because it was not returning the object the requirejs expected. This was fixed with this commit:
https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/commit/d847dd6a5a6bf501156ed74defb3914e43185ed6

Hope it will help.